# xcodebuild: error: unexpected duplicate task: CopyStringsFile

Tags: cocoapods

I am updating latest full version Xcode 10, CocoaPods 1.5.3.

I create chat library for my big project, I have multiple pod libraries in my chat library so I run pod install and it's working fine for building and running the app. But since my lib is used for others big projects I need to send my lib to github and pod.

I have this error message when do pod validation before I send my lib 'pod spec lint'
**xcodebuild: error: unexpected duplicate task: CopyStringsFile**
due to localization. I have 7 languages with each strings files and it's error all of them. I am using this [Localize-Swift](https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift) to help localization far more easier.

> I already tried CocoaPods beta 1.6.0 it's not working too.

What should I do?